# Client wants Protection for copyrighted photos on his portfolio site? What is the most painless way to do this?

Tags: css

I know it is impossible to completely protect his photos; I've explained that the best way to do this would be to watermark the images, but he wants some additional protection. I don't want to load my page with more JavaScript, because I feel like there are a dozen and a half ways of copying images which that script would need to handle. Is there a simpler CSS solution that will put his mind at ease?

Comment: I doubt CSS can handle "a dozen and a half ways of copying images".

Answer (score 2):

Simon's answer is very annoying.  A better solution that achieves the same thing (not able to right click on the image and save it) is to put a transparent gif on top of the image.  Still won't stop determined people, but is far less annoying to your honest viewers.

Simply put, any solution that's done client-side is VERY easily worked around.  You need to focus on server side solutions.  Watermarks, referrer checking (making sure the referrer is the page itself, also stops hot linking in most cases), reducing the image quality perhaps..

Answer (score 1):

You could make it slightly more annoying by having the images be background-images of some other element. This would only prevent the most obvious right-click>download image method.

That said, be **very careful** that you have an agreement, in writing, from him that states that he understands that this is simply an impediment to copying, and can easily be bypassed. The last thing you want is to be liable for not protecting his images when someone does manage to copy them.

Comment: I added an explanation that it would only prevent the most obvious right-click>download image method. Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it slightly annoying by adding and overlay layer of a transparent div over the images, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/WHEK3/3/

Edit: of course, this is an easily circumventable option to somebody who knows what they are doing, or knows how to use the developers tools in Chrome or firebug.